# Application crash on new thread starts

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

why this application crashes on new thread starts, please somybody point out me have i done enything wrong..

newthread.h

```
   #ifndef NEWTHREAD_H
    #define NEWTHREAD_H
   #include <QThread>

    class newthread: public QThread
    {
        public:
           newthread();

        public slots:
            void run();
     };

     #endif // NEWTHREAD_H
```

newthread.cpp

```
    #include "newthread.h"
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include<QDebug>

     newthread::newthread()
     {
     }

    void newthread::run(){
       qDebug()<<"thread executed";
    }
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include <QtGui>
       #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include"newthread.h"



     MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
     {
        setupUi(this);
      connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(opthread()));

       }

    void MainWindow::opthread(){
    newthread th;
     th.start();
     }
```

here in the main window there is a public slot called ophthread(). as shown above when a button in the main window is pressed that slot will trig. in it i i declared a newthread object called th and th.start() to start it. have i done enything wrong.

this compilles without errors. but when run the binary it gives a error and crashes.

my second question is if i need the thread to write some text on a textEdit in the main window how to do that. is it possible newthread class access objects in the mainwindow class.

Comment: have you tried to debug the program? Most debuggers can tell you where exaclty the crash happens.

Comment: `run` should be `private` (or `protected` in some cases), definitely not `public slots`. And do not subclass QThread! It's invalid use in most cases. And you can't access GUI element outside main thread, you need to use signal-slot message system to deliver data to the main thread.

Comment: in deabugger it says that it crashes on a segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're creating the thread with: -

```
newthread th;
```

It will then go out of scope and get deleted, which is not what you're wanting.
You need to dynamically create the object: -

```
newthread* th = new newthread;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
void MainWindow::opthread(){
    newthread th;
    th.start();
 }
```

You are creating the thread object on the stack. He will be destroyed when the function `opthread` returns. And from the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#dtor.QThread) :

> Deleting a running QThread (i.e. isFinished() returns false) will
>   probably result in a program crash. Wait for the finished() signal
>   before deleting the QThread.

You need to provide a greater lifespan for your newthread object. waiting for it to be finished is not an option, as it will result in a sequential execution. Either you use class members or you allocate your thread objects on the heap.

Personal opinion:
Not only sub-classing QThread is not the most appropriate method of getting it done, I believe you don't need a thread at all.